# Как сделать, чтобы колонка имела ширину , не меньше чем слово?

Tags: c#, csv

Данные сохраняются в CSV файл. В каждой колонке свои данные. Но некоторые слова , в помещаются в колонку и их полностью не видно. Пробовал открыть файл. Сделать колонки нужные по ширине, но при перезаписи файла, они становятся стандартными.
Данные заносятся из List . С#.
Как сделать , чтобы колонки, динамически подстраивались под длину самого длинного слова?

```
public void Conver(string path = "", string nameFile = "Empl", string delimiter = ";")
    {
        using StreamWriter writer = new($"{path}{nameFile}.csv", false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
        writer.WriteLine($"Фамилия{delimiter}Имя{delimiter}Возраст");
        if (persones == null)
            return;
        foreach (var cart in persones)
        {
            writer.WriteLine($"{cart.LastName}{delimiter}{cart.FirstName}{delimiter}{cart.Age}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: В csv не содержится информации о ширине колонок, он на то и примитивный comma-separated values формат, что не имеет никаких специфичных метаданных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказано в комментарии, формат CSV (comma-separated values) содержит только данные, без метаданных.

Однако, пользователями хочется просматривать такие данные в простых текстовых редакторах наподобие Блокнот/Notepad в удобном виде. Поэтому иногда применяется формат TSV (tab-separated values): в качестве разделителя выступает символ табуляции.

```
string delimiter = "\t"
```

В результате колонки будут иметь минимальную ширину, равную длине символа табуляции. Но эта ширина различается в разных приложениях. Обычно она равно 8 символам по умолчанию. Но может быть и 4.
Вот так оно выглядит в браузере (у меня в Файрфоксе длина табуляции 4):

```
Фамилия Имя Возраст
L0  F0  0
L1  F1  1
L2  F2  2
L3  F3  3
L4  F4  4
```

Вот так оно выглядит в Notepad (длина табуляции 8):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если длина значения в колонке превышает длину табуляции, то форматирование нарушается:

```
Фамилия Имя Возраст
LongLast0   LongFirst0  0
L1  F1  1
L2  F2  2
L3  F3  3
L4  F4  4
```

---

При желании можно задать длину колонок программно.

```
int maxLastNameLength = "Возраст".Length;
int maxFirstNameLength = "Имя".Length;
int maxAgeLength = "Фамилия".Length;

foreach (var value in persones)
{
    if (value.LastName.Length > maxLastNameLength)
        maxLastNameLength = value.LastName.Length;
    if (value.FirstName.Length > maxFirstNameLength)
        maxFirstNameLength = value.FirstName.Length;
    if (value.Age.ToString().Length > maxAgeLength)
        maxLastNameLength = value.Age.ToString().Length;
}

string format = $"{{0,-{maxLastNameLength}}}{delimiter}{{1,-{maxFirstNameLength}}}{delimiter}{{2,-{maxAgeLength}}}";

using StreamWriter writer = new($"{path}{nameFile}.txt", false);
writer.WriteLine(format, "Фамилия", "Имя", "Возраст");
if (persones == null)
    return;
foreach (var cart in persones)
{
    writer.WriteLine(format, cart.LastName, cart.FirstName, cart.Age);        
}
```

Проходим по всем значениями коллекции и рассчитываем максимальное значение длины для каждой колонки.
Потом конструируем строку формата. Она будет выглядеть так:

```
{0,-10};{1,-10};{2,-7}
```

Эту строку формата используем в методах `WriteLine`.

Результат получается наподобие:

```
Фамилия   ;Имя       ;Возраст
LLL       ;FFF       ;0      
L         ;F         ;1      
LLLLLLLLLL;FFFFF     ;2      
LL        ;FFFFFFFFFF;3      
LLLLL     ;FFFF      ;4
```

---

Напоследок не могу не отметить крайне кривой нейминг.
`Conver` - что это значит?
`persones` - что это значит? Если это коллекция типа `Person`, то должно быть либо `persons`, либо `people`.
Почему переменная цикла зовётся `cart`?

И не используйте кодировку 1251. Сейчас стандартом де-факто является UTF-8.

Comment: Александр спасибо !!! То что нужно было!  О нейминге замечания учту обязательно. Хорошая критика для начинающего.  Это вроде как черновой вариант разработки, но все равно,  понял, что и в черновом уже должно быть правильно.  Спасибо за помощь!!!